# How should I shim a foundation vent?

Tags: vent, brick, foundation, replacement

I bought some new foundation vents that attach with tension screws instead of mortar.  I chiseled out my old vent and with the new vent in place, there is a large gap. How do you recommend I fill the remaining gap to prevent rodent intrusion?  I was thinking about adding a small brick with some mortar on one side to fill the 1.5" gap. I was hoping to not need mortar for installation.

Link to the vents: http://www.lowes.com/pd_17140-228-RABL_0__?productId=3593660&Ntt=foundation+vent&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Dfoundation%2Bvent&facetInfo=

[image]

[image]
[image]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vent is almost the same size as the masonry opening in width, since the vent is plastic, I would use a table saw to reduce the top and bottom flanges to get it to fit between the top and bottom row of brick and trim the edges the small amount needed as well.

After that, set the vent inside the brick opening enough to bear against the mortar that is still in the opening. Hopefully that is at least 1/2". I think it would look better if it was an inch at least, but it is not needed. It only needs to be deep enough to form an inside corner to take a bead of caulk to seal out the unwanteds.
Or if you choose, you can tuck in a little mortar around the perimeter to do the same, but the more the vent is recessed, the more durable the repair will be. That means you might need to remove the original mortar to do so.It would be good to dampen the brick slightly first if you choose the mortar route.

Good luck.

PS. If you want to be sure that no vermin will get through, chisel out the rest of the masonry cement, (stay away from the outside corner, they will chip off in a heartbeat) dampen the brick as mentioned before and smear some mortar into the opening before you push in the vent, some mortar will inherently squeeze around the frame, the mix will need to be like a peanut butter maybe even toothpaste looseness. After the vent is set, place the remaining cement around the perimeter, this will lock it in real good.
Then again caulk will do pretty good too.

Answer (score 0):

Since the vent is held in mechanically otherwise, I would center it in the opening and just use spray in foam to fill in around the vent.

Comment: The problem with expanding foams like Great Stuff is that rodents will chew through it.  They are the primary reason for the vents being replaced.

Comment: Is there still a visible gap if the vent is centered?